# Time duration in Google Data Studio

Tags: time, looker-studio

I have some data I collect regarding length of time that's stored in HH:MM format. The data is in relation to sleep patterns (i.e. sleep duration, time fell asleep, etc...).

I am trying to import the data in Google Data Studio (DS) as a numeric variable, but it appears as text. I can see in DS there is a duration (seconds) numeric format, how can I convert a text variable into a numeric one?

It would be easier to convert the fields in a Google Sheet, but I need them as HH:MM for other calculations.

Comment: An easy option might be to add another column with the time as seconds in your Google Sheets?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

**0) Create a new Calculated Field**

**1) Seconds**
Use a formula to convert the Time values to a single value in Seconds, where `HH:MM:SS` represents the field name:

```
( CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(HH:MM:SS, "^(\\d{2})") AS NUMBER ) * 60 * 60 ) + ( CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(HH:MM:SS, ":(\\d{2}):") AS NUMBER ) * 60 ) + CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(HH:MM:SS, "(\\d{2})$") AS NUMBER )
```

**2) Change Field Type**
- Numeric > Duration (sec.)

Credit to [Google support community](https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/11358654?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [TODATE](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7037300) or MINUTE and SECOND function into a calculated field to extract minutes and second from a date. However don't expect to display minutes and second datapoint on a line chart in Data Studio, timeserie charts only support hour-level data at a minimum.